# Remove duplicates after a count but also removes count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, duplicates

I am trying to use 2 datasets to do a count and after I want to remove the duplicates from Col 1 but i want to keep the number of calls.

Basically I have a df like this:

| Client Number | Call Count |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 3 |
| Bob | 3 |
| John | 1 |
| Bob | 3 |

So what happens is the duplicates get removed but the call count also changes and turns to 1. How do I stop this from occurring?
If anyone can please help

`#Count the number of times a account number comes up CallCount['Call Count'] = CallCount.groupby('Client Number').cumcount() + 1`

`# Remove the duplicates  df2 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=["Client Number"], keep=False)`

I have tried these but its the same outcome

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'c': ['Bob', 'Bob', 'John', 'Bob'], 'n': [3, 3, 1, 0]})
df1 = df1.groupby(['c'], as_index = False).count()
df1
```

|  | c | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Bob | 3 |
| 1 | John | 1 |

This is what you are trying to achieve right?

Comment: yes i do but the dataframe I'm using has 9000 rows is there a better solution instead of writing it one at a time?

Also i want to remove the duplicates and keep the counts

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. The solution that i have posted removes the duplicates and keeps the count in `n` column. It works 9000 rows or even more.

Can you please post how exactly the output should look like?